# Is there a function to put all array elements in single subarray?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have an array with subarrays in it which contain multiple elements. For a calculation I need all these array elements to be in single subarrys.
So it needs to go from this [[a,b,c][d,e,f]] to [[[a][b][c]][[d][e][f]]]
Is there any function that can do that for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can write one:

```
a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]

for i, arr in enumerate(a):
     for j, val in enumerate(arr):
             arr[j] = list(val)

# output: [[['a'], ['b'], ['c']], [['d'], ['e'], ['f']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any built-in functionality, but it's quite straightforward to write your own recursive function for that:

```py
def to_single_subarrays(arr):
    # If arr is a single element without being an array,
    # wrap it in an array
    if not isinstance(arr, list):
        return [arr]

    # If arr is an array of length 1, just return it,
    # it's already what we want.
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr

    # If arr is an array with multiple elements,
    # recursively process every single element, then join the
    # results back together
    return [to_single_subarrays(el) for el in arr]

data = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
print(data)
print(to_single_subarrays(data))
```

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
[[['a'], ['b'], ['c']], [['d'], ['e'], ['f']]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a built-in function to make the code look nicer, but I guess I'll just stick to a loop then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
def function(oldList):
    newList = []

    for i in oldList:
        newList.append([])

        for j in i:
            newList[len(newList)-1].append([j])

    return newList
```